# Set up initial connection to MySQL using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm totally new to MySQL and have been working through the Node.js tutorials on w3schools.  I've downloaded the MySQL community server and have installed the MySQL module through npm on Terminal.

I have a .js file containing the following code to try and create a connection:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: " "
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

When I enter the default password given to me from downloading MySQL and try to run it in the terminal using 'node myfile.js' terminal keeps throwing these errors:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
```

So I'm hoping someone can either A) tell me what I'm doing wrong or B) show me how to change the password because the only other thing I can think of is if I incorrectly copy/pasted the password and now I can't connect.

Thank you and I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: can you connect to your database with the CLI ?

Comment: Is that different than Terminal?  I just assumed Terminal was the command line.

Comment: It is the terminal. But I want to see if you can connect to your db this way or if it fails too

Comment: No I can't connect to my database through the terminal

Comment: Is your password a single space  `password: " "` or is it and empty string `password:""`?

Comment: The password is a string I just didn't enter it here

Comment: if you can't connect to the database through the terminal, then you have a problem with your database.

Comment: So what is the solution? Should I uninstall MySQL and start over?  All I've done so far is download and try to connect.

Comment: Reset the password for `root` user and try logging in again. If it works, then put the password in node and try. It might work.